# Referring to equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, citing, cite-package

I'm preparing a journal paper using "osajnl" style. My question is that, how can I refer to equation and its source reference as the below photo. [image]
in other words, I'm trying to use equation (1) from reference 7 in my mathematical derivations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the optional argument to the `\cite` command. With the `osajnl` class the `\cite` macro has two optional arguments, where the first places text before the citation, and the second places text after the citation. If you only supply one, this is placed before, so you need to add an empty first optional argument:

```
\documentclass{osajnl}
\journal{ol}
\begin{document}
\cite[][Eq.~13]{article-full}
\bibliographystyle{osajnl}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used this command but it shows the equation first, then the reference as [ Eq, (13), 1]. is there anyway to make it looks like what you have done? Note that I'm using class(osajnl)

Comment: @KhaledAlhamawi Try `\cite[][Eq.~13]{citationkey}`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given the hint, that the blue number be the pagenumber, you could define a new command `\mathref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}             % to get blue color

\newcommand{\mathref}[1]{%
  [\textcolor{blue}{\pageref{#1}}, Eq.~(\ref{#1})]}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

Pythagoras formulae is presented on \mathref{eq:1}.
\end{document}
```

This will produce this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the blue color is the reference number.
I'm trying to use equation (1) from reference 7 in my mathematical derivations.

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood your question.  I am sorry for that.  In that case, Torbjørns response is the right solution for you.